How do I change a column of single-value Python tuples into integers?
As part of a class assignment, I have received a dataframe which has a data value associated with a single-value tuple:
d = {'value': [0.827278, 0.586009, 0.832050, 0.576557, 0.943456],
 'userId': [(75,), (106,), (686,), (815,), (1040,)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

I need to deploy userId in a merge, onto an ID column in another dataframe which is integer-valued, and that obviously returns an error since userId is a tuple. How do I convert userId into an integer column consisting of the first value in each of those tuples? All of my attempts to do something like df['userId'] = df['userId'][0] return errors. (You can assume that the first value in each tuple is guaranteed to be an integer; I've checked that.)

You can index with .str:
df['userId'] = df['userId'].str[0]

Result:
      value  userId
0  0.827278      75
1  0.586009     106
2  0.832050     686
3  0.576557     815
4  0.943456    1040

Or use Series.str.get:
df['userId'].str.get(0)


Worked great, thanks!

I used the basic principles of python, might be a bit tidy and codier.
# get values of the key
x = d["userId"]
print(x)
myList = []
print(type(x))
# x is a list whose values are tuples
for item in x:
    print(f"Item is {item} and type is {type(item)}")
    # try to convert them into string
    newItem = str(item)
    # perform striping
    stripedItem = newItem.strip("(),")
    integerValue = int(stripedItem)
    myList.append(integerValue)


print(myList)
# check if the item in myList are values
for item in myList:
    print(f"Item is {item} and type : type{type(item)}")

